# Is it possible to use 3 webcams at once using Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to use 3 webcams at once using Flash AS3?

Hello, I am using the below code to display 3 webcams at once.
But it only works with 2.
    getCamera ("0") and getCamera ("1") = ok
    getCamera ("1") and getCamera ("2") = ok
    getCamera ("0") and getCamera ("2") = ok
    getCamera ("0") and getCamera ("1") and getCamera ("2") = NOT

```
var cameras = Camera.names;
trace('Cameras: '+cameras);

// Cameras: Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000,Integrated Webcam,USB2.0 Camera,IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]
// Camera.getCamera("0") = Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000
// Camera.getCamera("1") = Integrated Webcam
// Camera.getCamera("2") = USB2.0 Camera

var camera0:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0");
camera0.setMode(400, 300, 100); 
camera0.setQuality(0,100);
var video0:Video = new Video(); 
video0.smoothing = true;
video0.width = 400;
video0.height = 300;
video0.x=0;
video0.y=0;
video0.attachCamera(camera0);
addChild(video0);

var camera1:Camera = Camera.getCamera("1");
camera1.setMode(400, 300, 100); 
camera1.setQuality(0,100);
var video1:Video = new Video(); 
video1.smoothing = true;
video1.width = 400;
video1.height = 300;
video1.x=400;
video1.y=0;
video1.attachCamera(camera1);
addChild(video1);

var camera2:Camera = Camera.getCamera("2");
camera2.setMode(400, 300, 100); 
camera2.setQuality(0,100);
var video2:Video = new Video(); 
video2.smoothing = true;
video2.width = 400;
video2.height = 300;
video2.x=800;
video2.y=0;
video2.attachCamera(camera2);
addChild(video2);
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific runtime errors, or are you simply not seeing the 3rd feed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done this (a couple of years ago, so memory is a little foggy). As stated above, any errors? Are the cameras all the same brand/model or different? Are you using the special (and sometimes buggy) Flash player that comes with Chrome, aka "Pepper Flash". Have you tried other other browsers, other OS's?

Comment: I hadn't tried using three cameras on a single system, but we had run into some issues with two that might be carrying over to three.  It's not a limitation of Flash AFAIK, but with the internal USB configuration (I'm assuming they're USB cameras), where cameras on the same bus would have bandwidth sharing issues.  We basically punted and watched carefully which ports we plugged the cameras into to get consistent behavior.  I don't know if Firewire cameras would help.

Comment: No error message appears.
Cameras are different brand and model.

They always leave in their respective USB port.
If you put the code to show only two (any of) the two standard works.
If I put the 3, so the only work 2/1 of the code.

if I put the camera in this sequence: 0 1 2 works only 0 and 1
if i put this sequence 0 2 1 0 and only works 2
if i put this sequence 1 2 0 only works on 1 and 2

Comment: I think it is not issue of the Flash Player or Flash ActionScript. It may issue with USB configuration and Handling Web-Cam stream at System level (means at USD Web-Cam driver level).